# group date range with specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know there's lots of grouping in date range. I've looked in the internet. But the one's I saw was hard wired range. Say,

```
CASE
   WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2014-3-30' THEN 1
   WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2014-4-1' AND '2014-6-30' THEN 2
   -- And so on
END
```

That only covers the Year `2014`, right? But what if I need to also cover for the next 4 years or so. Do I really need to `manually` put it in the query? Or is there a way for it to cover for the next coming years?

In specific, I need to group the records by range. `Aug` to `Jan` (group 1) and `Feb` to `July` (group 2)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MONTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

```
CASE
  WHEN month([Date]) BETWEEN 2 AND 7 THEN 2
  ELSE 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
group by 
         case when Month(DateCol) IN (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1) then 1 
              else 2 
         end
```

Ref: [Month()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187813%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)