# group by date range by month,year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have here a sample [data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41ac6). And I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351525/group-date-range-with-specific-range) before which worked but as I tested it farther I forget the fact that I should also account the `Year` for it.

So in a nutshell, I want to group the record by month range. `Aug` to `Jan` (group 1) and `Feb` to `July` (group 2). Because I want to `count` of how many school objects were created for every 6 months. An on going trend to be specific.

A result set such as:

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| sc_object | count | range         |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| pencil    | 1     | 2013-8 2014-1 |
| eraser    | 1     | 2014-2 2014-7 |
| pencil    | 1     | 2014-2 2014-7 |
| sharpener | 1     | 2014-2 2014-7 |
| pencil    | 1     | 2014-8 2015-1 |
| eraser    | 1     | 2015-2 2015-7 |
| pencil    | 1     | 2015-2 2015-7 | 
| sharpener | 1     | 2015-2 2015-7 |
| eraser    | 1     | 2015-8 2016-1 | 
| sharpener | 2     | 2016-2 2016-7 | 
| pencil    | 1     | 2016-2 2016-7 |
| sharpener | 1     | 2016-8 2017-1 |
| eraser    | 1     | 2016-8 2017-1 |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
```

Any help would be much gladly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41ac6/19):

```
WITH cteRanges
AS
(
    SELECT
            site,
            CASE
              WHEN MONTH(date) IN (1) THEN CAST(YEAR(date) - 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-8' + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1'
              WHEN MONTH(date) IN (8, 9, 10, 11, 12) THEN CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-8' + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(date) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1'
              ELSE CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2' + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-7'
            END AS range
    FROM
            test
)

SELECT
          site,
          COUNT(*),
          range
FROM
          cteRanges
GROUP BY
          site,
          range
ORDER BY
          range,
          site;
```

You calculate the ranges based on the month and year, then aggregate your results.

Comment: @BoyPasmo: You're welcome.  You got downvoted cuz you didn't provide any code, but I looked into your profile and realize SQL's not really your thing.  No worries, but pay it forward, please. ;)